# C++ Optimizing reading of Binay File

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, binary-search-tree, c++17

I have a binary file(format: little Endian size 2GB) which contains two dataSet(one fixed and one variable) multiple times. First Data Set is fixed and second data set next two bytes have a count value which tells how much big data set is. I am able to read the file into a vector and trying to find the count and data of those two structures. But My code is taking too much time. I want to optimize my solution. I know the starting two bytes of both the headers. can some please suggest me some optimize way. Thank you for the help.

```
DATASETONEFORMATSIZE 270
DATASETTWOFIXSIZE 36

const uint8_t dataSet1[2] = { 0xAD, 0xBE };
const uint8_t dataSet2[2] = { 0x5E, 0xCA };

std::ifstream file(myfile, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
std::streamsize size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(size);
std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator itBuffer;
if (file.read((char*)buffer.data(), size))
{
    for (itBuffer = buffer.begin(); itBuffer != buffer.end(); itBuffer++)
    {
        uint8_t CheckBytes[2] = { *itBuffer, *(++itBuffer) };

        if (CheckBytes[0] == dataSet1[0] && CheckBytes[1] == dataSet1[1])
        {
            ndataSet1++;
            itBuffer += (DATASETONEFORMATSIZE - 2);
        }
        else if (CheckBytes[0] == dataSet2[0] && CheckBytes[1] == dataSet2[1])
        {
            ndataSet2++;
            ++itBuffer;
            uint8_t nCount[2] = { *itBuffer, *(++itBuffer) };
            uint16_t result = nCount[1];
            result = (result << 8) | nCount[0];
            itBuffer += 20;
            ++itBuffer;
            std::vector <uint8_t> tempSampleData(result);
            tempSampleData.assign(itBuffer, (itBuffer+result));
            itBuffer += (result + 11);
            std::for_each(tempSampleData.begin(), tempSampleData.end(), 
                 [](const auto &e) 
                  {std::cout << static_cast<int>(e) << " "; });

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If your code works and you are wondering how to optimise it, CodeReview is the place for your question, not StackOverflow.

Comment: without actually testing the code I would venture to guess that by far the largest amount of time in your code is spent writing data to cout... but as @Fureeish said this code does not belong here if it works

Comment: I think xception is on to something. Other than that, depending on your compiler, you may find that using discrete variables for the check bytes and data sets is faster than using arrrays.